# Black shadow on custom select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use fancySelect.js in my project, [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8jwkju6L/1/).

I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="emergency-nos" id="emergency-nos">
    <option value="">Emergency numbers</option>
    <option value="">91 + test number</option>
    <option value="">91 + test number</option>
</select>
```

I am initializing the plugin, like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#emergency-nos').fancySelect();                
});
```

Everything works fine, except there is a small glitch when the selectbox is clicked and then when you click the second time, the select box folds as expected, but there is a blackish shadow around the select box; why am I getting this shadow when the select box folds?

That black shadow is really kind of spoiling my UI, I have modified quite a lot of the CSS myself to suit my theme, but done nothing to add that blackish shadow, why am I getting that black shadow ?

Comment: Please look into developer tools on the browser. For e.g. [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/workspace/setup-devtools). F12 will bring this dev tools up on Chrome, IE etc.

Comment: @Lobo have you ever heard of the clitch `lobo marta bobo`  ?

Comment: @Lobo , it mean `lobo is screaming` , its in a language called konkani (goa , india), i stayed in goa for a few years and heard the locals say that LOL.

Comment: Haha. I know. Konkani is my mother tongue. I asked because you are Russian and I didn't know if it meant anything in Russian. Now go look into dev tools. :-P

Answer (score 2):

remove this from css:

```
div.fancy-select select:focus + div.trigger {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #4B5468;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `box-shadow` entry on your css.

```
div.fancy-select select:focus + div.trigger {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #4B5468
}
```

You could also just hide the `select` element.